# Последовательное исполнения команд

Tags: node.js

Есть небольшой код, который удаляет файлы.

```
    var files = fs.readdirSync("/test");
    _.each(files, function(file) {
.. код
        api.sendMessage("Passive");
    });
    removeDirForce("/test");
```

Проблема в том, что removeDirForce срабатывает раньше, чем обрабатываются все файлы. Как задать последовательность выполнения? Чтобы функция удаления каталога срабатывала после обработки всех файлов?

Comment: понимаю, что можно сделать внутри цикла fs.unlink("/test/"+file); но мне хочется разобраться

Comment: можно конечно заменить на обычный for, но тогда падает производительность

Answer (score 0):

._each -асинхронная функция. Либо положите `removeDirForce("/test");`в колбек как-то так:

```
     var files = fs.readdirSync("/test");
        _.each(files, function(file) {
    .. код
            api.sendMessage("Passive");
            removeDirForce("/test");
        });
   Либо промисами..
```

Comment: ну окей, а если мне надо сообщение отправить и не в конце, а вначале. колбек не поможет. как тогда быть? я вопрос создавал не ради конкретного примера) а принцип понять.

Comment: В начале чего? Разбейте желаемую последовательность по пунктам: 1,2,3....

Comment: пункт 1: sendMessage, пункт 2: все sendMessage из цикла, пункт 3: sendMessage после всего.